# Android Manifest change force closes app

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I added a class to my working app. I want the new class to be the first page to load, its called dashboard.class. I added it to the manifest and now the app force closes when you try to load it. I also went and removed the entry in the manifest and the app worked again. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.MagicBuddy.Gamble.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The dashboard is the new class I added. When I remove it and reset MainActivity to LAUNCHER and MAIN, the app will work just fine again.

I tried the posted solutions of removing the intent-filter and it is still crashing. Here is the logcat **Also thank you guys for your replys

01-31 13:56:38.709: D/AndroidRuntime(1995): Shutting down VM
01-31 13:56:38.709: W/dalvikvm(1995): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2eda288)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.magicbuddy.gamble/com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:25)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-31 13:56:38.709: E/AndroidRuntime(1995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)

I added a class that has only 4 buttons on it and each button has an image. That is what I want to load first but this is the logcat error when I try to make that happen

Comment: 1. Please post your LogCat. 2. Are you sure you need the action `com.MagicBuddy.Gamble.MAINACTIVITY`?

Comment: According to logcat the problem is `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button` on `onCreate()` in your `Dashboard.java` class. You are casting an `ImageButton` to a `Button`. The problem is not in the manifest but in the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logcat the `Exception` is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.Button

This is happening in the `onCreate()` method of your Dashboard `Activity`. You are casting an `ImageButton` to a `Button`. The problem is not in the manifest but in the class itself.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on how to do an image over a button so I am unsure what I am doing wrong

Comment: I got it working, I had 3 of the 4 buttons listed as image buttons and the 4th was just a normal button. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `intent-filter` from your MainActivity. You really only need to define intent filters when trying to control what types of intents access into your activity, but if that is only going to be called upon by your Dashboard activity as I think it is, then you don't need to include the intent filter as it is part of the same package